# Multiple views for one document in Childframe with MDI Application

Tags: view, mfc, mdi, doc

I have a questions about MFC application.
Nowadays I'm maintaining legacy MFC project. And there is a huge problem.
We are not using document class for view class. so for example, There is a child frame that made of 3 views. Three of them use almost same data. But each views get the data by themselves not from document. so there are a lot of duplicated code.

I want to solve this and refactor. So I searched for how to link views and doc in a child frame. And all samples were about CMultiDocTemplate constructor. 
following is what I tried.

```cpp
CMultiDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
pDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_MFCApplication3TYPE,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCApplication3Doc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), 
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCApplication3View));
if (!pDocTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);

pDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_MFCApplication3TYPE,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCApplication3Doc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), 
    RUNTIME_CLASS(MyTreeView)); 
if (!pDocTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);
```

If I used like above, it asked which frame you want to show. It wasn't not what I wanted. It was a different frame.

I want to make multiple views and one document in a same child frame.
And I also tried this way.

```cpp
CMultiDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
pDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_MFCApplication3TYPE,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCApplication3Doc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), 
    NULL);
if (!pDocTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);
```

NULL for a view. And create views in a child frame's OnCreateClient()

```cpp
BOOL CChildFrm::OnCreateClient(LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs, CCreateContext*     pContext)
{
   m_wndSplitter1.CreateStatic(this, 2, 1);
   m_wndSplitter2.CreateStatic(&m_wndSplitter1, 1, 2);
   m_wndSplitter3.CreateStatic(&m_wndSplitter2, 2, 1);
   m_wndSplitter3.CreateView(1,0 , RUNTIME_CLASS(CTestView), CSize(200, 300), pContext);
   m_wndSplitter3.CreateView(0,0 , RUNTIME_CLASS(CTestView2), CSize(200, 200), pContext);
}
```

It can create multiple views well. But I don't know how to link CTestView,CTestView2 and one document. 
When I approach document class in a TestView, I only can approach to CDocument that is base document class. 
I want to approach specific document like CTestDocument.

Is there any way?? If there, Please let me know.

Thanks for reading my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a common practice in MFC to add a GetDocument( ) member to views.

```
//.h
#ifndef _DEBUG
    CTestDocument* GetDocument( ) { return dynamic_cast< CTestDocument* >( CView::GetDocument( ) ); }
#else
    CTestDocument* GetDocument( );
#endif

//.cpp
#ifdef _DEBUG
CTestDocument* RaRichView::GetDocument( )
{
    assert( dynamic_cast< CTestDocument* >( CView::GetDocument( ) ) );
    return dynamic_cast< CTestDocument* >( CView::GetDocument( ) ); }
#endif
```

You will want to change CMFCApplication3Doc with CTestDocument so it is the document opened for your frame.

Answer (score 1):

When a view is created the document it belongs to is passed in the CCreateContext.

The document template has the simple function CMultiDocTemplate::CreateNewFrame. With this function you create a new frame/view combination with an existing template.

Also there is the function CFrameWnd::CreateView taking a CCreateContext...